# Getting duplicate products while fetching products via WooCommerce Product Listing API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

For one of the woo-commerce stores, I am getting same product in response with different related_ids attribute while calling `/wp-json/wc/v1/products`.

I have checked record of first 10 pages and found that for every page I am getting same product with same product ID  but different `related_ids` attribute.

It seems single product has many related products and I am getting this product as many times as `related_ids` attribute varies.

Is there any way(filters or config) to stop getting duplicate product when store has related products?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch products by using `offset` params. Starting from offset=0 and increase it in each iteration.

`/wp-json/wc/v1/products?filter['offset']=x*100&per_page=100`. Increase the value of x in each iteration.

Here is the link : https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v1.html#pagination